# Using Scala match case with lists

Tags: scala, generics, callback, pattern-matching

I would like to use the `match case` statement using lists. Here is my use case:

```
val test: String = "test3"
val option: String = getMyOption(test) match {
  case Some(o: String) => o
  case None => ""
}
test match {
  case `test1` | `test2` => doSomething(test, option, param1)
  case `test3` | `test4` | `test5` => doSomethingElse(test, param1, param2)
  case `test6` => doMyJob()
  case `test7` => doMyJob(param2, param3)
  case other =>
    throw getUnsupportedTestOperation(other)
}
```

I tried the following, but it seems like the functions are evaluated before the matching because I get a `NullPointerException` from the `doSomething(test, option)` function (which wasn't supposed to be called in the `test3` case).

```
def matchList[T](string: String, cases: => Map[Array[String], T], exception: => Exception): T = {
  val matched: Option[T] = cases collectFirst {
    case (list, matching) if list.contains(string) => matching
  }
  if(matched.isDefined) matched.get else throw exception
}

val mapping1: Array[String] = Array("test1", "test2")
val mapping2: Array[String] = Array("test3", "test4", "test5")
val mapping3: Array[String] = Array("test6")
val mapping4: Array[String] = Array("test7")
val option: String = getMyOption(test).getOrElse("undefined")
val testMapping: Map[Array[String], Unit] = Map(
  mapping1 -> doSomething(test, option, param1),
  mapping2 -> doSomethingElse(test, param1, param2),
  mapping3 -> doMyJob(),
  mapping4 -> doMyJob(param2, param3)
)
matchList(test, testMapping, getUnsupportedTestOperation(other))
```

In this case I pass `Unit` functions like callbacks, but I would also like to use other types (ex: `String`, `Array[String]`..). What do I miss? How could I avoid the evaluation of the `Map` content before the matching? Is it possible to use lists in a `match case` statement? Or is there an easier way to achieve that? (I would like to avoid having an `if` statement inside the `match case`.)

**Edit**

What I ended up with

```
def matchList[T](matchCase: String, matchClause: => ListMap[List[String], T], exception: => Exception): T = {
  val matched: Option[T] = matchClause.find(_._1.contains(matchCase)).map { case (_, output) => output }
  if(matched.isDefined) matched.get else throw exception
}
```

Usage

```
def testMatchList(input: String, option: String, exception: Exception): Unit = {
  val testMapping: ListMap[List[String], () => Unit] = ListMap(
    mapping1 -> match1(input),
    mapping2 -> match2(input, option),
    mapping3 -> match3(),
    mapping4 -> match4(option)
  ) //  where matching cases signatures looks like => def match1(...): () => Unit = () => ...
  val method = scalaHelper.matchList(input, testMapping, exception)
  method()
}
```

*NB: Don't know yet how I could extract `testMapping` out of the `testMatchList` definition...*

Comment: Using `.get`,`.orNull` is at best not idiomatic, and probably code smell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `doXXX` calls will occur at the creation of `testMapping` unless you actually make them to be function values of type `() => ()`.

Here a simple way to achieve what you want:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

class A
class B1 extends A
class B2 extends A

def do1(value: String): A = new B1
def do2(value: String, anotherValue: String): B2 = new B2
def do3(): A = new A

val matchClause = ListMap(
  Set("test1", "test2") -> do1 _,
  Set("test3") -> (do2(_: String, "your other value"))
   Set("test4") -> (_: String) => do3()
)

val test = "test1"
val a: Option[A] = matchClause.find(_._1.contains(test)).map { case (_, method) => method(test) }
```

Note the use of `ListMap` rather than `Map`. It is mandatory to ensure that overlapping cases are executed in the order that the clauses are declared, like it would be for a normal pattern match.

Of course, this is all very ugly and I would advise against it unless your original pattern match becomes really impossible to read. Compare my answer to your first code block: the simple `match` is *much clearer*, and is also very likely *more efficient*.

Comment: I'm looking for a list based solution as this pattern match will quickly grow and I want to be able to update it by just adding new cases to a list. I agree with your efficiency concern, but I do not on the readability & maintainability. Also, I'm not really worried about the `ListMap` as there will be at most one match in my use case. The later is also the reason why I used the `collectFirst` method. So, how can I make a `Unit` method become a `() => ()`?

Comment: @belgacea My answer does what you need, you simply need to use `do1 _` instead of actually calling `do1(test)` when declaring the clauses. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, but what about the case where the function doesn't take any parameter? Same for the case where it does take parameters but others than `test`. I don't need it in all my functions. Is there a way to declare a function call with parameters and then calling it by value using the already given parameters? Maybe I should change my functions signature from this
`def doMyJob(...): Unit = { ... }` to something like this `def doMyJob(...): Unit = () =>  { ... }`?

Comment: The problem with this is that you can’t store functions with differing arities (number of parameters) in the `Mapˋ, because the values would have type ˋAny`. What you can do is take a parameter anyway and just ignore it. I will edit my answer to match your new example.

Comment: My answer was edited. Of course, this is still limited to a map containing either `String => Aˋ, so you have to convert `() => Aˋ to it by just discarding the String